# Play Scala Accessing Path in a JSON tree via a List

Tags: json, scala, playframework

In Play Scala, We can navigate through properties in an object using the \ method:

```
val name = (json \ "user" \ "name")
```

How can we navigate to the node if my path is defined in a list

```
val path = List("user","name")

val name = (json \ path ) // Gives Error
```

I am able to do this via the following

```
val nn = path.foldLeft(json: JsValue)( (b,a)=> b.\(a))
```

**Edited:**

Actually I want to access the node from the list while creating the read Combinators in Play Scala

```
implicit val placeReads: Reads[JsonParse] = (
 (JsPath \ **path**).read[String]
)(JsonParse.apply _)
```

Comment: Are you confused that play-json doesn't have such method which accept list as parameter and return value of anode in JSON structure?

Comment: @maks I have edited my post. Yes I am confused. I want to know is there any way I could access the node by providing list of parameters.

Comment: foldLeft seems to be right way to go.

Comment: @Biswanath But How should I use that path in Read Combinator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write

```
implicit val placeReads: Reads[JsonParse] = (
 (path.foldLeft(JsPath)((a,b) => a \ b)).read[String]
)(JsonParse.apply _)
```

?

**EDIT**

Try

```
JsPath(path.map(KeyPathNode(_)))
```

Comment: No it is not working. I am getting the error : 
Expression of type JsPath doesnot conform to expected type JsPath.type